# How to deploy android app to be able to resolve end user issues

Tags: android, debugging, deployment, logging

I am new to android development and presently writting a small android application for the android market.

I would like to resolve application bugs when end users face them..

So, What is the best way to be able to collect issues from the end user of the application.

Should i store logs of my app to a file on the SD card ? and then somehow provide an interface in the app to send me that log by email ?

Or is there any already placed mechanism in android to facilitate this ?

Currently I have statements like

Log.i (TAG, "Message..");

and

Assert.assertNotNull(strSomething);'

Also please advise if they would go in the deployed code ??

Essentially what I would like to get to be able to fix issues is a stack trace of crash (if any) and any log file with my app messages..

Please advise...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For user's running Android 2.2+ with the Android Market (Google Play) installed, they will be prompted to "Report" errors if an uncaught Exception or other problem occurs. You'll be able to [view these error reports](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/google-feedback-for-android.html) in your Android Market developer account.

You'll also be able to [view statistics](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/new-app-stats-for-publishers-on-android.html) on what types of devices your application is installed on.

There are 3rd party services that offer more fully-featured error reporting, but I've found the built-in tools to be more than adequate.

If you find and fix a bug, you can release a new application version via the Android Market and your user's will be prompted to upgrade.

Comment: Hi thanks @twaddington but what if there are not exceptions but user complains that a feature is not working ..?? Does Google play forwards the logs as well which we normally see in logcat while debugging ??

Comment: If the user reports an error Google will include device details and some exception details in the error report. Generally these will not include your custom log messages.

You can ask a user having a specific problem to install an app like CatLog and email you their log messages. However, this requires to you have direct contact with the user having an issue (example: they have emailed you).

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat

Comment: This answer does not take account of Javascript errors. If you've got a web app (not a native Android app written in Java), then any error that breaks Javascript will not show up in the error reports, and users will complain and you will have no idea what broke the Javascript. See my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971718/what-is-causing-my-web-app-to-stall-on-some-android-devices-how-do-i-detect

Comment: You can send logs to logcat from the Android browser using the console methods (log, info, warn, error): http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html